# Xcode Compilation Issue

Tags: ios, compilation, xcode7

I have no clue why there is a compilation problem with storyboard. Following is the screenshot of the issue:-

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Please suggest what could be the reason.

Comment: 1) Try clean and build 2) Delete derived data

Comment: Tried clean and build many times over. Haven't tried deleting derived data. Will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Deleted derived data. still doesn't work!! Some problem with writing Main.storyboard to derived data, i think. Because LaunchScreen.storyboard and all other files are present in desired data but Main.storyboard is not present in derived data.

Comment: Open up your Build Phases and look under Copy Bundle Resources. Look at the Main.storyboard. Is that shows up twice in this list

Comment: Nope. Only present once. I am deleting last two VCs i added, maybe some problem with VCs within the storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with second last VC i added. Don't know why but First Responder is initial placed and View Controller is second placed, Refer following screenshot:-

[image]

After removing this VC, compilation succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Delete derived data folder under xcode this helped me to solve the issue